# CSS3: How to select every 4th and 5th element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm new to these selectors and I was wondering how I would go about doing such a thing.

My selector needs to select the 4th and 5th elements, but then it needs to keep doing so. So it'd need to select 4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15 and so on.

How is this possible? At the moment I can select every third item like so:

```
.pure-g-r .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(3n+3)
```

But I'm not sure how I can translate that into what I need.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Imo you don't have to select it both in one selector. You can go something like this : `.pure-g-r .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(3n+1), .pure-g-r .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(3n+2)`

Comment: You can't select them in such order "4, 5, 9, 10, 14, 15". 9 is what 4n+1, 14 is what 4n+2, so this is not "each" element, but some random.

Comment: @Itay yep my bad it can be done that way, and add another selector just for the 4 element...

Comment: @Phill BTW - `3n+3` is the same as `3n`

Comment: @Phill Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You actually want to select every couple from the 4th and 5th element, with jumps of 5.

So, just use the following two comma-separated selectors.

```
.pure-g-r .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(5n + 4), .pure-g-r .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(5n)
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/taN4d/)

[image: Result]

Comment: @ABFORCE BTW - A better way of writing the selector in your (deleted) answer is simply `:nth-child(n + 4)`. No need to use `not`

Answer (score 1):

a little nth-child tester page: http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/

```
.pure-u-1-3:nth-child(5n + 4), .pure-u-1-3:nth-child(5n){
    color:red;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/

http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/